# cant get .jsp working in apache tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

i cant get a JSP file loading in Apache tomcat v8, on eclipse its working fine 100%

i have these .jar files in the WEB-INF/lib both on eclipse and remote server apache

```
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
```

HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

why does this work locally and not on my remote server using the exact same jar files?

web.xml @ this location /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<web-app       xmlns="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"; 
xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; 
xsi:schemaLocation="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee xmlns.jcp.org/xml
/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"; version="3.1" metadata-complete="true">
```

web.xml @this loc /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<web-app xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"; 
xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; 
xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
/web-app_2_4.xsd"; version="2.4">
```

Comment: What do you mean by on eclipse? You started your tomcat V8 through eclipse or do you use something else?

Comment: And what kind of Apache is the remote server? There is a plethora of servers provided by the Apache project. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: I have the JSP file running smoothly running on Apache tomcat v8 on my local host ... I have a seperte Apache installed on a virtual machine on a remote sever (fi-ware) however when I try run the jsp on the virtual machine (fi-ware) I get uri error even though I use same jsp and jar as the ones on my local machine (eclipse and windows) ... Markus apologies on my weak attempt of a question but please do take your sarcasm and watch paint dry thanks

Comment: Please post your `web.xml` file.

Comment: posted two web.xml ( edit q) thanks josh

Comment: The URL `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core` is obsolete for a looooong time. The correct URL is `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: edited q) with exact error 
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application